# Free program to create 3d transparent geometric figures inside another 3d transparent geometric figures and rotate it

Tags: gratis, drawing, 3d, geometry

I need to draw a 3d cylinder inside another 3d cylinder, and then rotate it to get different perspectives.

Comment: Welcome!  What operating system(s)?  Can you provide any more details?

Comment: [Read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what i needed ,in case someone else ends up needing it :
https://www.thortspace.com/

Comment: The link doesn't seem to do what the question asked for. It is a mind mapping tool. An interesting one, but not what is asked for.

Comment: You can't 'draw a 3d cylinder inside another 3d cylinder, and then rotate it ', but you can create spheres inside another spheres, and rotate it. Its the best i could find. Also, is much easier then others animations related programs.

Comment: Pretty much any 3D modeling program will do what the question asks for. Some are designed for children and are pretty easy to learn.

Comment: Could you suggest those that are easy to learn ?

Comment: A google search gives many hits. You might try TinkerCAD. I haven’t but it’s supposed to be easy. https://www.tinkercad.com/